# Control is not waiting even though i have used the await in nodejs server

Tags: node.js, https, async-await

I'm building an application in which the user has to verify using the OTP. I'm generating the OTP but not able to send it to the user as the control is not waiting even though I have used await

```
exports.generateOtp = async (req, res, next) => {
var phoneNumber = req.params.phonenumber;
var otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, { alphabets: false, upperCase: false, specialChars: false });
var data = '';
var generatedJson;
var url = "https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=myapikey&senderid=ID&channel=OTP&DCS=8&flashsms=0&number=" + phoneNumber + "&text= Your OTP for registration is " + otp + " Maltose Bio Innovations &route=31";
try {
    var request = await https.get(url, function (result,) {
        result.on('data', function (chunk) {
            data += chunk;
        });
        result.on('end', async function () {
            generatedJson = JSON.parse(data);
            console.log(generatedJson.MessageData[0].MessageId);
            const newOtp = new OTP({
                code: otp,
                messageId: generatedJson.MessageData[0].MessageId
            })
            newOtp.save();
        })
    }).on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error: " + err.message);
    });
    await res.status(201).json({
        message: 'OTP Generated',
        messageId: generatedJson.MessageData[0].MessageId
    });
} catch (err) {
    next(err);
}
}
```

I'm able to send the SMS and get the message ID and save it in the database too but I'm not able to send the same message ID as a response the in API

Stack trace.

App TypeError: Cannot read property 'MessageData' of undefined
2YHZ0FD9NU6RhrkHdpIKJA

the JSON response from the URL is

{ ErrorCode: '000',
ErrorMessage: 'Success',
JobId: '53****2',
MessageData:
[ { Number: '9191******09',
MessageId: 'IKjXq5FOzUmB2PvxeBvqoA',
Message:
'Your OTP for registration is 378472 Maltose Bio Innovations' } ] }

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using 'https' module. The method `https.get()` is not asynchronous, so you cannot 'await' its result. As so, you may need to use promises to wait for result.
The second thing I'd suggest is getting rid of `var` and use `let` or `const` instead.

```
exports.generateOtp = async (req, res, next) => {
    const { phoneNumber } = req.params;
    const otp = otpGenerator.generate(6, { alphabets: false, upperCase: false, specialChars: false });
    let data = '';
    let generatedJson;
    const url = "https://www.smsgatewayhub.com/api/mt/SendSMS?APIKey=myapikey&senderid=ID&channel=OTP&DCS=8&flashsms=0&number=" + phoneNumber + "&text= Your OTP for registration is " + otp + " Maltose Bio Innovations &route=31";

    const asyncGetData = () => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            https.get(url, (result) => {
                result.on('data', function (chunk) {
                    data += chunk;
                });
                result.on('end', async function () {
                    generatedJson = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log(generatedJson.MessageData[0].MessageId);
                    const newOtp = new OTP({
                        code: otp,
                        messageId: generatedJson.MessageData[0].MessageId
                    })
                    newOtp.save();

                    resolve(generatedJson);
                })
            }).on("error", (err) => {
                console.log("Error: " + err.message);
                reject(err);
            });
        });
    }

    try {
        const response = await asyncGetData();
        res.send(201, {
            message: 'OTP Generated',
            messageId: response.MessageData[0].MessageId
        });
    } catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
}
```